# Manipulate timestamp (GMT to given UTC), using an SQL function in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

The objective is to group data stored with a GMT 0 timestamp, by month/day/hour - according to the client's UTC time (meaning, client's timezone offset should be added to the timestamp).

In SQL, the query should look something like (when grouping by days):

```sql
SELECT   * 
FROM     myentity 
GROUP BY dayofweek ( date_add (mytimestampcolumn, INTERVAL timezonedifference hours ))
```

In JPA, the following code works fine as "dayofweek" is a known (registered) function to jpa:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
Expression<Integer> timeUnitFunction = criteriaBuilder.function("dayofweek",  Integer.class, from.<Date>get("timestampColumn"));
query.groupBy(timeUnitFunction);
```

It however, does not consider the timezone offset, so I'd like to use another db function and change the second line into something like:

```
criteriaBuilder.function("dayofweek", Integer.class, criteriaBuilder.function("date_add", Date.class, "hour", timezoneDifferece,  from.<Date>get("timestampColumn")))
```

Only `ADD_DATE` and `ADD_TIME` are not, from what I could see, registered JPA functions.

Using a custom dialect for calculating a simple timezone offset seems like an overkill.

Any suggestions on an alternative JPA registered function that can manipulate timestamps or any other way to get wanted results (Correct grouping by month/day/hour on a varying timezone offset) would be much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
As commented by Neil, date_add, along with any other SQL function, is invokable by `CriteriaBuilder`'s function method.

I couldn't however, provide [date_add](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)'s required argument of "INTERVAL expr unit" format (using `CriteriaBuilder.literal` to create a String Expression didn't work).

**Problem was solved** using the SQL "[convert_tz](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)" function with String literals as the timezone values.

Comment: what do you mean "not registered JPA functions" ? The "function" method allows you to invoke *any* SQL function in your JPQL - the first arg is the function that will appear in the SQL.

Comment: @NeilStockton thx for the reply, so how can i convert the expected "ADD_DATE" SQL function args "(timestamp, INTERVAL timeZoneOffset HOUR)", to an "Expression<Date>"? as that's the type of arg CriteriaBuilder's function method expects to represent the SQL function args?

Comment: depends what you want to input, a literal? or value of a field that is of the right type? The second arg of cb.function is a Class and you haven't done that.

Comment: @NeilStockton Apologies. The second arg should be Date.class, as edited just now. i want the input to be the timestamp column from.get("timestampColumn")) which is of the type "Expression<Date>" and the second arg, which represents the offset in the original SQL function and is in "INTERVAL integer TIME-UNIT(DAY / HOUR etc...)" format, i'm not sure how to put.

Comment: "cb.literal(the_value)" would convert the value into an Expression

Comment: @NeilStockton, Thx a lot, i couldn't use cb.literal() to convert the value into a proper "INTERVAL value unit" format, but i could use it to create timezone values for the CONVERT_TZ function which suits my needs better anyway. Please write your answer regarding the invokability of SQL functions and creating their literal args using cb methods and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `cb.function(sqlFuncName, args)` method to invoke any SQL function. The *args* are Expressions, pass in as many as your SQL function needs. If these *args* are literals then you can make use of `cb.literal(value)` to convert it into an Expression.

Maybe with these components you can generate something that meets your purpose. Note that by invoking an SQL function you may be losing RDBMS portability, but that may not be a concern for your situation.